# Ng-Click is not working in directive with Compile

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm writing a fairly simple AngularJS directive which is a button.
The basic directive does look like:

```
officeButton.directive('officeImageButton', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            isDefault: '@',
            control: '=',
            label: '@',
            image: '@'
        },
        template: '<div class="button-wrapper" ng-click="onClick()">' +
                    '<a href="#" class="button image-button">' +
                      '<img src="{{image}}" />' +
                      '<span>{{label}}</span>' +
                    '</a>' +
                  '</div>',
       // Reset of the code not included for readability - See below.
    }
}];
```

Inside this directive, I do have a controller defined:

```
/**
 * @description
 * Provides the controller for the 'officeImageButton' control. In this controller, all the required methods and
 * other information is stored.
 */
controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
    // Allows an API on the directive.
    $scope.api = $scope.control || {};

    /**
     * @kind            Click
     * @name            onClick
     *
     * @description
     * This function is executed when the user click's the button itself.
     */
    this.onClick = function() {
        if (typeof $scope.api.onClick === 'function') { $scope.api.onClick(); }
    }
}],
```

And then I have my `link` function:

```
link: function(scope, element, attributes, controller) {
    /**
     * @kind            Event
     * @name            onClick
     *
     * @description
     * Executes when the user click's the button.
     */
    scope.onClick = function() {
        controller.onClick();
    }
}
```

Since in the Template, I do have an ng-click attribute, the `scope.onClick` function is executed when I click the button. This behaviour is expected.

But now, in my directive, I need to also use the compile function in order to render the button correctly which is showed below:

```
compile: function(element, attributes) {
    var floating = attributes['float'];
    // When there's floating, make sure to add the class 'floated' to the image.
    if (floating) { $('img', element).addClass('floated'); }
    // When there's right floating on the element, make sure to place the iamge after the <span> element.
    // In case of left floating, nothing needs to be changed.
    if (floating === 'right') {
        var imageElement = $('img', element);
        $(imageElement).remove();
        $('span', element).after(imageElement);
    }
},
```

But with this `compile` function included the `ng-click` isn't working anymore.
Any toughts on what I'm doing wrong here?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `compile` function's return value is the pre- and post-`link` functions, so when you define a `compile` property, the `link` property is ignored. And since you are not returning that link function in the compile, the `scope.onClick` is not on the scope.

To fix, you'd need to refactor a bit:

```
compile: function(tElem, tAttrs){

   // whatever you do now

   return function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
     scope.onClick = function() {
        ctrl.onClick();
     }
}
```

**Off-topic:**

Also, note that you don't need to create an `onClick` in the controller. The controller's use in the directive is to act as an API to other directives that `require` it.

I presume that you did mean to have `officeImageButton.onClick` to be invoked like that by another directive? If you did, that's fine - but otherwise it is redundant - just use the `link` function to define elements on the scope.